# How to shutdown and start a server in Python Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, trial

My client (based on twisted) is supposed to automatically reconnect to server when connection is lost, i need to make a test of this feature, here's my test method where the @todo comment is very clear about what behaviour is expected:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def test_reconnect_on_connection_loss(self):
    client = SMPPClientFactory(self.config)
    client.reConnect = mock.Mock(wraps=client.reConnect)
    # Connect
    smpp = yield client.connect()

    # Bind
    yield smpp.bindAsTransmitter()

    # @todo: A connection loss is expected here
    #        the client is supposed to try reconnections
    #        for a while, the server then shall start
    #        again and the client will get connected.

    # Unbind & Disconnect
    yield smpp.unbindAndDisconnect()

    ##############
    # Assertions :
    # Protocol verification
    self.assertNotEqual(0, client.reConnect.call_count)
```

On the server side, am trying to abort connect just after receiving a bindAsTransmitter request:

```
class LooseConnectionOnBindSMSC(SMSC):

    def handleBindAsTransmitter(self, reqPDU):
        self.sendSuccessResponse(reqPDU)

        # Connection is aborted here:
        self.transport.abortConnection()
```

The connection is successfully aborted, my client starts trying to reconnect as expected but it never get the way to get my server UP again.

Comment: Jean paul, yes the server still listen when i abortConnection server side ... i need a way to stop listening for some seconds and then start again.

Answer (score 2):

Your server is still running (as far as anyone can tell from the code in your question).  Closing one connection to a client doesn't stop the server from accepting new connections.

The way to stop a listening port from listening is with `port.stopListening()` (note that it returns a `Deferred`).  You can start listening on the port again with another `reactor.listenTCP` (or whichever API you used to start listening the first time) call.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.